# Expand div when the content overflows

Tags: css, html, overflow, expand

I have div with height="400px" and width="25px".How to expand div when the content overflows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use stylesheets and change

```
 width:25px;
```

to

```
 min-width:25px;
```

AND

```
 height:400px;
```

to

```
 min-height:400px;
```

Comment: Perhaps changing "height" and "min-height" may be more suitable?

Comment: @cez :- Thanks I edit my answer so that it expands vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want it to expand horizontally?

Comment: I have a `main` tag with `min-height` set and no `height`, and has `div` children, but `main` is not expanding to contain the children. Instead, the children are just overflowing. The `footer` is at the top of `main`'s content because `main`'s actual size is tiny.

Answer (score -4):

At the risk of setting my self up for angry eyes from everyone else, just use a table, it will behave as you describe.

Comment: In my case , I can't use a table.